# Woocommerce: Add own templates for single product pages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to be able to add a template for a single product page in Woocommerce and then be able to choose which template i want for every product like you have on a normal page(look at the image below). Is something like this possible in Woocommerce?

[image]

Comment: You can take some help from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190335/woocommerce-change-template-for-single-product-page.